# Creating a box in UI image using line renderer not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm planning to create a square inside UI image using line renderer but size is too small that you need to zoom In. but if its outside the UI image its working. Please see attached imaged below

[image]

the line renderer component is attached to redkey1spawn object.

Tried derHugo code it works but somehow it overshoots in the screen

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask], [tour] and [mcve] to improve your question to get an answer

Comment: you should probbaly rather use an Image with an according sprite instead. Create the image file e.g. with photoshop or Paint with transparent background and a 1px frame. Than in Unity you could configure the Sprite Editor in order to not scale the frame but only the center of that texture -> Use `Sliced` as fill method for the Image and you have a 1px frame regardless the scales of the image.

Comment: @derHugo thank you for the recommendation sir but I needed the line renderer for my game. Is there anyway I can instantiate line renderer inside ui image or panel w/ its correct size.

Comment: Is your `canvas` in `Screenspace Overlay`?

Comment: @derHugo yes canvas is in screenspace overlay

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the LineRenderer works with coordinates in Unity Units.

A `Screenspace Overlay` canvas has pixel size scaling so the width and height (in Unity units) match up with the width and height (in Pixels) of the Window.

→ since you add 4 points

```
0,  0, 0
2,  0, 0
2, -2, 0
0, -2, 0
```

in worldspace it means they actually on the canvas will use e.g. `2px, -2px, 0px` → very small.

You could e.g. multiply the sizes by the height or width of the image/canvas.

```
private void Start()
{
    var lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    var image = GetComponentInParent<RectTransform>();

    // get the Unity worldspace coordinates of the images corners
    // note: to get the scales like that ofcourse only works
    // if the image is never rotated!
    var worlsCorners = new Vector3[4];
    image.GetWorldCorners(worlsCorners);
    var imageWorldSize = new Vector2(Mathf.Abs(worlsCorners[0].x - worlsCorners[2].x), Mathf.Abs(worlsCorners[1].y - worlsCorners[3].y));

    var positions = new Vector3[lineRenderer.positionCount];

    var pointnum = lineRenderer.GetPositions(positions);
    for (var i = 0; i < pointnum; i++)
    {
        positions[i] = positions[i] * imageWorldSize.x;
    }

    lineRenderer.SetPositions(positions);
}
```

---

**Note**, however, I'm actually not even sure you will see this LineRenderer since it is not a UI component I'm pretty sure the ScreenSpace Overlay will make every Image etc always render on top of it.

Comment: I tried your code but when I print the result of positions variable it says no value actual result says UnityEngine.Vector3[]. I tried attaching the line renderer component on game object and even adding the line renderer component via script using this myLine.AddComponent<LineRenderer>().

Comment: Did you configure a positions count/size in the inspector? If not you'll have to do so via script as well `lineRenderer.positionCount = 4;` before calling `GetPositions`

Comment: your code works but encountered a problem please refer my main post.

Comment: well .. that's just using the values you gave me and an example how to recalculate the target size ... I don't know what exactly you are expecting or what all your project settings are (canvas scaling, image anchoring, size etc)

Comment: Thank you sir you give me an idea on how to aproach my problem